# discrete_distrubution of struct

Tags: c++, c++11

I had a `vector` of real values:

```
vector<double> values;
```

and a `discrete_distribution`:

```
discrete_distribution<size_t> dis(values.begin(), values.end());
```

But now I need that the vector of `double` values becomes a vector of structures:

```
struct Data
{
   double value;
   int index;
};

vector<Data> values;
```

How can I build the corresponding `discrete_distribution` without making a copy of the values into a separated `vector`?

Comment: Template argument in `discrete_distribution` must be integral.

Comment: @101010 you mean like `int`, why?

Comment: There's a list of types that are valid, and `size_t` isn't one of them. That said, on almost all platforms `size_t` is a typedef of one of the supported types, but that doesn't make the code strictly correct. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can use the following overload ([number 4](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution/discrete_distribution))

```
template< class UnaryOperation >
discrete_distribution(std::size_t count, double xmin, double xmax,
                      UnaryOperation unary_op);
```

like this.

```
std::discrete_distribution<int>
make_distribution(const std::vector<Data>& weights)
{
  const auto n = weights.size();
  const auto op = [&weights](double d){
    const auto index = static_cast<std::size_t>(d - 0.5);
    //std::cout << "weights[" << index << "].value == " << weights[index].value << "\n";
    return weights[index].value;
  };
  return std::discrete_distribution<int> {n, 0.0, static_cast<double>(n), op};
}
```

It should work but it is a kludge.

Comment: Please, write how you would instantiate a discrete_distribution object considering N=100 values, which value is in the range [0, 1].

Comment: @Nick Sorry, my initial thought was not correct.  Please see the update answer.

Comment: Can you explain the value assigned to index?

Comment: @Nick The formula is in the documentation that can be found at the link given in my answer. If you put in these numbers, it happens to generate a sequence `0.5, 1.5, …, n - 0.5`.  Subtract `0.5` and you'll get the index.

Answer (score 0):

Boost has a [transform_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html) that can convert the return value of an iterator:

```
const double get_value(const Data & d)  { return d.value; }


auto beg = boost::make_transform_iterator(values.begin(), get_value);
auto end = boost::make_transform_iterator(values.end(), get_value);
discrete_distribution<size_t> dis(beg, end);
```

(based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/491069/321772))

Comment: I can not use boost. How can I get the same result by using only the std library?